# Installshield The specified File key not found in the File table

Tags: winforms, setup-deployment, installshield-le

I've packaged my WinForms app with the Visual Studio Installshield Limited Edition wizard.

When installing the app, I get this error during installation.

```
Error 2715. The specified File key ('myappname.xml_serializa') not found in the File table
```

Any ideas from anyone?  I'm completely loss on this one.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? What type of installshield wizard?
I'd recommend using the Orca tool to examine the MSI file you are using, there are a lot of tutorials online. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.  I'm using VS2012 and the default built-in Installshield option for winforms.

Comment: There isn't any default installshield option for winforms in VS2012.

Comment: Well, I added a new project in VS2012, chose Other Projects, and selected 'Setup and Deployment'.  Then I selected the only available option of Installshield, and went through the wizard step-by-step.

Comment: What level of VS2012 do you have? I have Premium and there isn't a default option for installshield. It might be Installshield LE.

Comment: I understand your question now.  I was thinking of what option for Installshield, and not what Edition.  But yes, it is Installshield LE.

Comment: In my case I made a mistake when i clicked the buttom Add project output. Check if it's the same in your case.

Answer (score 12):

In your installer project directory, open the *.isl file and search for the text in your error message, myappname.xml_serializa.  It will most likely be in there quite a few times.  Either remove it or correct all instances of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.  I've opened the isl file in Visual Studio and did a search just for 'serializa', but there were no matches.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem recently and found out that it didn't find the key because I was not adding the **.primaryoutput** file on the section Specify Application Data -> Files. Check if you are adding all the necessary files for your setup before creating the installer. The installer will be created even if it doesn't have all the files, but it won't execute properly.

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked for me when I combined it with stricq's answer above: first remove all references to the component in the .isl file, then add the files in Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

Changing the *.isl file resolved our issue. I found that we had changed the .NET framework of a project and when we removed the project output from the Installshield using the prompt it did not update this file so when we added the output again it now contained two outputs. OUTPUT and OUTPUT1. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me: The project in my case was readonly as it was connected to TFS. If you are working offline, make sure you make the project files writable. (Uncheck Read Only at the folder level)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. In your setup project double-click Project Assistant.
2. Click on Application Files.
3. Select file(s) with the file extension that was reported in the error message(s).
4. Click on Delete.
5. Repeat for any files as needed.
6. Go back to setup project in Solution Explorer.
7. Click on Rebuild